# jQuery check for part of Index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array or objects and I need to find a key that contains part of a string, not the value associated with the key. Can `inArray` do this or is there an alternative?

Example array has a key with `form_iQc2lz6yr7[contactName]` and a value of "John Smith". I need to search in this array for the key containing the string "[contactName]" as the string before this can change but `[contactName]` will always stay the same. Then I need to change the key to just "contactName".

Example:

```
[
  {name: "action", value: "someUrl"},
  {name: "list", value: "123344"},
  {name: "form_iSfMSWen3Y[contactName]", value: ""},
  {name: "form_iSfMSWen3Y[email]", value: ""},
  {name: "form_iSfMSWen3Y[subject]", value: ""}
]
```

Full context, I need to submit this form via ajax then once that is complete, change the key of form_iSfMSWen3Y[contactName], form_iSfMSWen3Y[email], and form_iSfMSWen3Y[subject] to contactName, email, subject, respectively and then submit to another url.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you question. Can you please provide a fiddle or a sample code for it? What does it mean array has index 'blablabla' with value 'ads'? In this case it is not an array? Is Object.

Comment: I have a form that I'm submitting via ajax and I serializeArray() it. I need to change the index because I actually submit it to two different endpoints and the second one needs the index to be a different name.

Comment: array[oldIndex] = array[newIndex].

Comment: jeff, this would assume I know the original key, correct? I need to check if the key contains part of a string as the key is randomly generated on form load but will contain at least [contactName] at the end

Comment: It would really help if you edited the question to show an example of the arrays content and the values you want to find, along with your own attempts to achieve this so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: ok let me grab it and I'll post it.

Comment: Updated. I changed the terminology a bit after reading serializeArray() docs. I wasn't familiar the the difference between key and index and array of objects, just in previous cases I could use them fine. This task is outside anything I've tried before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in one `.map()`

```
obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
}

required_keys = jQuery.map(Object.keys(obj), function(val, i) {
  if (val.indexOf("_abc") != -1) {
    return obj[val];
  }

});
document.write(required_keys);
```

or If you want key/values you can do like

```
obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
}

required_keys = jQuery.map(Object.keys(obj), function(val, i) {
  if (val.indexOf("_abc") != -1) {
    return {[val]:obj[val]};
  }

});
document.write(JSON.stringify(required_keys));
```

Comment: My object/array is result of running serializeArray() on a form. So I'm checking the key to have a partial string of....

Comment: I've tried this several times/ways but it doesn't seem to match the key by partial string, as I've tried to console log a message on match.